# Datatable - Remove table class properties set header width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

**Dynamically generated table structure using Datatable**

```
<table id="resource_report" width="70%" class="table dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row"><th align="left" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 135px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;" aria-label="
                Week 1&amp;nbsp;(1-4)
                : activate to sort column ascending">
                Week 1&nbsp;(1-4)
                </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px;" aria-label="
                Week 2&amp;nbsp;(5-11)
                : activate to sort column ascending">
                Week 2&nbsp;(5-11)
                </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 111px;" aria-label="
                Week 3&amp;nbsp;(12-18)
                : activate to sort column ascending">
                Week 3&nbsp;(12-18)
                </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 111px;" aria-label="
                Week 4&amp;nbsp;(19-25)
                : activate to sort column ascending">
                Week 4&nbsp;(19-25)
                </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="resource_report" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 111px;" aria-label="
                Week 5&amp;nbsp;(26-31)
                : activate to sort column ascending">
                Week 5&nbsp;(26-31)
                </th></tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

**CSS class applied from bootstrap-default.css**

```
.table thead th {
    background-color: #16a085;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Tried removing using below but not working

```
$(resource_report).removeAttr(" color:'', background-color:'' ");
```

The table header appears like below 
[image]

and like this after you press F12 or inspect element

[image]

1. How do I remove properties of the class `table thead th` so that
   `background-color` and `color` is not applied without changing
   anything in CSS file?
2. How do I make table header appear correct taking proper width and not look compressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the `<th>` widths it is caused by default text wrapping. Prevent this by

```css
#resource_report th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I cannot find a similar *bootstrap-default.css* anywhere, but just overwrite your tables `background-color` to whatever you want with

```css
#resource_report th {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

`yellow` just for demonstration, as another mentions - you could use `transparent` as well. The above will not inflict on any other "boostrapped" element, just your `#resource_report` table (I believe that is your real concern) - using jQuery to change CSS properties is a little bit overkill when the same can be achieved by a single line of CSS.  **http://jsfiddle.net/0hgen4o6/**

---

If you for some reason *really* want to use jQuery, then use at least the correct selector :

```js
$('#resource_report thead th').css('background-color', 'red');
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0hgen4o6/1/**

Comment: This is not working `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#resource_report').css({"white-space":"nowrap"})
    });`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, no - it does not work because you are not using the correct selector (as the last part of my answer states) - **if** you insist of using jQuery, even though there is no reason to do so - you must at least use the correct selector `$('#resource_report thead th').css('white-space', 'nowrap')` is the same as the CSS -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0hgen4o6/3/** `$(resource_report)` does (at best) point to the jQuery dataTables instance, not its headers - therefore it does not prevent wordwrapping anywhere :-)

Comment: I have already added `#resource_report th` in style. and shows no difference. But if I click on thead or press F12 it shows the correct width. I am using tabbing to show it. Might that be the reason of the table header getting compressed ?

Comment: hey @Slimshadddyyy, can you paste the complete markup into one of the fiddles? Perhaps including a reference to that bootstrap-default.css? I just need the markup / code. I think you are into some kind of XY-problem (the real problem is propably different from what we are trying to solve here)

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy - this is the _rendered_ markup, including what dataTables inject when you initialise a table, I was thinking about your markup :)  fiddle with bootstrap correct loaded -> http://jsfiddle.net/0hgen4o6/14/

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you meant by my markup. Although your last fiddle fits my issue, albeit header is not correctly displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was being caused by [`autoWidth`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) defaulting to `true`.

So all I had to do was explicitly set it to `false`:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  autoWidth: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty the properties as below:

```
$(resource_report).css({"color":"", "background-color":"transparent !important"});
```

For your second problem try providing `width:auto` or `100%` width to your table or alternatively your can trigger `window.resize` as I see that they are getting updated on console open which `resizes` the window..

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this $(resource_report).removeAttr("color,background-color");